# Hibernate persists lists with start index 1 instead of 0

Tags: java, hibernate

We use Hibernate to save a list of entities using `OrderColumn` to maintain their order.

```
class MyObject {

...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myobject", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
   @OrderColumn(name = "index_number")
       private List<sampleElement> sampleElement;
}
```

When saving the list of elements, the `index_number` starts with `1` while the documentation suggests it should start from `0`. This also causes an issue upon reading because the read list then contains a `null` element at position `0`.

We have looked around quite a bit and are somewhat out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be customized by using [`@ListIndexBase`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ListIndexBase.html).

> Defines the start index value for a list index as stored on the database. This base is subtracted from the incoming database value on reads to determine the List position; it is added to the List position index when writing to the database. By default list indexes are stored starting at zero.

```java
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myobject", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @OrderColumn(name = "index_number")
  @ListIndexBase(1)
  private List<sampleElement> sampleElement;
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-customizing-ordered-list-ordinal) of the hibernate documentation.